# Embedded appendChild JS files not re-fetched on browser hard refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I have a web page with multiple embedded JS files, almost all of which are inserted using the normal `<script src="/blah.js?v=20200414">` tag. They all have a cache-busting query string, based on the date they were created.

There is one script which is loaded using the following

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(loadScriptElm, 2000);
    function loadScriptElm()
    {
        var scriptElm = document.createElement("script");
        scriptElm.src = "/special-script.js?v=20200414";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(scriptElm);
    }
</script>
```

All the scripts have a Cache-Control for 900 seconds. The code in all of them runs just fine.

When I initially load the page, all the scripts are retrieved from the server. When I do a refresh (using F5), all the scripts are loaded from browser cache (assuming the cache TTL hasn't expired).

When I do a 'hard refresh' (using Ctrl+F5), all the 'regularly-embedded' scripts are re-fetched from the server (as I would expect), but the `special-script.js` file is not - it's still retrieved from browser cache. Why doesn't a hard refresh also re-fetch this file?

I can reliably recreate this on Chrome/Brave, but I haven't tried other browsers. It *seems* like a bug, but maybe it's not... Is this 'expected behavior'? If so, is it documented anywhere?